# Search specific fields in nested documents as one document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following structure:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "document": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "paragraphs": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "paragraph": {
                            "type" : "object",
                            "properties" : {
                                "content": { "type": "string"},
                                "number":{"type":"integer"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these sample documents

```
{
    "title":"Dubai seeks cause of massive hotel fire at New Year",
    "paragraphs":[
    {"paragraph": {"number": "1", "content":"Firefighters managed to subdue the blaze, but part of the Address Downtown Hotel is still smouldering."}}, 
    {"paragraph": {"number": "2", "content":"A BBC reporter says a significant fire is still visible on the 20th floor, where the blaze apparently started."}}, 
    {"paragraph": {"number": "3", "content":"The tower was evacuated and 16 people were hurt. But a fireworks show went ahead at the Burj Khalifa tower nearby."}}, 
    {"paragraph": {"number": "4", "content":"The Burj Khalifa is the world's tallest building and an iconic symbol of the United Arab Emirates (UAE)."}}]
}

{
    "title":"Munich not under imminent IS threat",
    "paragraphs":[{"paragraph": {"number": "1", "content":"German officials say there is no sign of any imminent terror attack, after an alert that shut down two Munich railway stations on New Year's Eve."}}]
}
```

I can now search each paragraph using

```
{ 
    "query": { 
        "nested": { 
            "path": "paragraphs", "query": { 
                "query_string": { 
                    "default_field": "paragraphs.paragraph.content", 
                    "query": "Firefighters AND still" 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: How can I wright a query that searches several paragraphs but only the content field?

This works, but searches all fields

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Firefighters AND apparently AND 1"
    }
  }
}
```

It is matching ***Firefighters*** from paragraph 1 and ***apparently*** from paragraph 2 which I want. I do however not want ***1*** to be matched since it isn't a content field.

**Clarification**: The first search performs a search per paragraph which I want some times. I do however also want to be able to search the whole document (all paragraphs) sometimes.

**Solution**
I added "include_in_parent": true as it is mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-nested-type.html

Comment: what is wrong with your first query? isn't it going through all paragraphs?

Comment: It is. But I do also want to option to search all paragraphs at the same time so that "Firefighters AND apparently" would return the document even though they are in different paragraphs

Comment: You can try writing a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are querying is wrong because `nested documents` are indexed separately. See the last para from the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-nested-type.html).

Your query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "paragraphs",
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "paragraphs.paragraph.content",
          "query": "Firefighters AND apparently"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is looking for both words in the **same** para and hence you are not getting the result. You need to query them separately like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "paragraphs",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "paragraphs.paragraph.content": "firefighters"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "paragraphs",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "paragraphs.paragraph.content": "apparently"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the right results.

As a side note I do not think you need `object datatype` inside paragraphs. Following will work fine too

```
"paragraphs": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
          "content": {
              "type": "string"
          },
          "number": {
              "type": "integer"
          }
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you, I went through the page and I needed to add      "include_in_parent": true to get it to work

Comment: glad I could help, didn't go for "include_in_parent" as it might increase index size considerably, but it will definitely work